# How to make random images load in ImageView android

Tags: android, random, bitmap, imageview, android-imageview

My app is about clicking on button and changing images in ViewImage , these images are from server. I tried to display one image and it is working but the problem that i can't display random images from server in my ViewImage.
Here s the code to display image from server:

```
package com.example.testurl;

 import java.io.InputStream;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.widget.ImageView;
 import android.widget.LinearLayout;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ImageView my_img;
Bitmap mybitmap;
ProgressDialog pd;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    new DisplayImageFromURL((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_image)).execute("http://www.tmonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/androidfigure.jpg");

}

private class DisplayImageFromURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> 

{
    ImageView bmImage;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pd.setMessage("Loading...");
        pd.show();
    }
    public DisplayImageFromURL(ImageView bmImage)
    {
        this.bmImage = bmImage;
    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) 
    {
        String urldisplay = urls[0];
        Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
        try 
        {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            System.out.println("Success");

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Erroooooooooooor");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return mIcon11;

    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
}
```

Here is the code for activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/back"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="test"
     />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_image"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

It is displaying just one image , i want it to display other images on server randomly when i click on button.
Thanks

Comment: pass random image urls to AsyncTask

Answer (score 1):

Create an array in array.xml like this:

```
<string-array name="url-array">
    <item>http://www.tmonews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/androidfigure.jpg</item>
    <item>url2</item>
    <item>url3</item>
    <item>url4</item>
    etc..
</string-array>
```

Then when the user clicks the button, use this to get a random string from the array:

```
String[] array = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.url-array);
String rdmStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
```

And finally pass `rdmStr` to your AsyncTask in stead of the url.

I didn't test it, but i think this will work.